# Cause path planning to take wider turns

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble getting my robot to find a path through doorways. Sometimes the global costmap just doesn't give enough space.
*A* solution is to decrease the inflation_radius,
however the result is that it plans paths with very tight corners, meaning sometimes the robot runs over items near the wall that stick out below the sensor level.

Is there a way to coerce the planner into accepting tight spaces when there is no alternative, like doorways, but take a wide birth around corners when it is possible?

It feels like a need another "inflation" box for "desired personal space".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213643/cause-path-planning-to-take-wider-turns/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an ancient question that never got one answer, so I'll throw up what I've found since 2015.

1. The now famous ROS Navigation Tuning Guide PDF by Kaiyu Zheng that came out in 2016, a year after this question was written: http://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf
   Especially pay attention to the part about creating a "gradient" for the local planner so every path is in the middle.
2. http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner
   I don't know why this isn't the default, it has worked **so much better in every way** than the seemingly more common dwa_local_planner, and teb works "out of the box" with no tuning required to just navigate a map.

---

Originally posted by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) with karma: 241 on 2020-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1